# Can rear height speakers be added in parallel?

Tags: surround-sound, atmos

I have a 7.2 channel Dolby Atmos receiver designed for 5.1.2. Would it be preferable in addition to the front height speakers, to add rear height speakers wired in parallel?  In other words, this would be a 5.1.4 configuration using a 5.1.2 receiver.

Or would I be better off only having the two front height speakers wired?  Would having the additional drivers coming from the rear mess up the psychoacoustics algorithm?  Does Dolby provide any guidance on this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

If a sound element has been directed in front height left by the sound mixer, why would you send it to a the rear left height speaker ?

It would mess up the artistic intent of the mix.